# Custom domain feature for saas ecommerce product customers

Tags: node.js, nginx, dns, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm currently working on a SaaS product using React.js and Node.js where we provide subdomains to customers upon registration (e.g., **subdomain.example.com**). However, we've received feedback from some customers expressing the need to use their own custom domains (e.g., **customdomain.in**) .

One crucial requirement is that we do not want customers to connect their custom domains directly to our server IP.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

We've attempted to set up a CNAME record for the custom domain

Name: **customdomain.in**
Target: **subdomain.example.com**

but unfortunately, it's not redirecting the requests as expected.